# Python - change directory to a folder based on what day of the week it is

Tags: python

I'm trying to automate an ftp upload with files that are in folders based on the day of the week.  Since today is Tuesday I would like to have the script go to the //server/folder/Tuesday folder, and upload the files in that folder.

I have this:

```
os.chdir("//MTR-SRV/Creative/CHARGER/Monitor/Out")
cwd = os.getcwd()

print "1", cwd
```

but that just gets me to the folder right before the day folder.
I need it to get to //MTR-SRV/Creative/Charger/Monitor/Out/Tuesday (or whatever today's date is)

any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can get the day of the week like this:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime('%A')
'Tuesday'
```

In your case, this ought to do the trick:

```
import time
dayofweek = time.strftime('%A')
os.chdir("//MTR-SRV/Creative/CHARGER/Monitor/Out/" + dayofweek)
```

Comment: Or, to make it more general, use `os.path.join()`. Also `datetime.date.today()` works as well as `now()` for this.

Comment: Or the shorter: `time.strftime('%A')`

Comment: Did not know about time.strftime, nice! Updated answer. @agf didn't use os.path.join since OP didn't, and I don't think he has any reason to support multi platform

Comment: @jterrace Yep, wasn't meant as a correction, just alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

dayname = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%A')
os.chdir("//MTR-SRV/Creative/CHARGER/Monitor/Out/%s" % dayname)
cwd = os.getcwd()

print "1", cwd
```